# Como faço para adicionar um prefixo antes da minha tabela no php?

Tags: php

Como faço para adicionar um `prefixo` antes da minha `tabela` no php?
Segue abaixo meu código:

```
$table = 'news AS N, news_category AS NC';

if (strpos($table, ', ') !== false) { 
    foreach (array($table) as $key => $value) {
        $db = $value;
    }
    echo $db;
} else { 
    echo 'FAIL'; 
}
```

Está me retornando o seguinte valor: `news AS N, news_category AS NC`

Bem agora gostaria de deixar assim: *`prefixo_`news AS N, `prefixo_`news_category AS NC*, dentro do código que compartilhei acima. Lembrando que não quero por isso: `$table = 'prefixo_news AS N, prefixo_news_category AS NC'` na variável `$table`, preciso por dentro do `if` ou `foreach.` É possível?

Comment: Esse seu loop foreach não faz nenhum sentido. O que você pretende? Não está bem claro o que você quer com esse código, e provavelmente a melhor solução não é a que você está imaginando.

Comment: Bem, sou iniciante, necessito de ajuda, eu desejo por o `prefixo`, me ajude criar um código bom?

Comment: Não é isso, você está montando um trecho de SQL, certo? Em que condições você precisa do prefixo e em quais não precisa? E para que serve a variável `$db`? Fica difícil te ajudar sem entender o que você está tentando fazer.

Comment: Beleza, vamos lá, estou montando um trecho de SQL por que as condições que vou precisar dele é na `function`, pois estou querendo montar uma única function com dois tipos de DB, a seleção de DB normal e a seleção de DB mult, a normal eu já tinho, está assim: https://pastebin.com/cJApMWgg agora quero por uma mult DB dentro dessa função, por isso estou usando a `if` com `strpos` para verificar se possui `,` na hora de escolher uma tabela

Comment: O que é uma mult DB? Enfim, o outro código parece certo, e tem inclusive tratamento de prefixo na tabela. Mas eu continuo sem entender sua dúvida.

Comment: multDB = vou abrir duas tabelas ao mesmo tempo, exemplo: TABELA: News e TABELA: News_Category, então lerá assim: readDB('news, news_category'); porém com o código que possuo, apenas entrará o prefixo na 1º tabela, ficando: readDB('prefixo_news, news_category'); é ai que entra meu problema, preciso que o prefixo entre na 2º tabela também ficando: readDB('prefixo_news, prefixo_news_category'); e assim em diante, se tiver 3 tabelas, 4, etc ... todas entrando o prefixo na frente.

Comment: Por tudo que você disse, eu criaria uma nova função para lidar com consultas que envolvam mais de uma tabela.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Divide uma array em partes e percorre os elementos adicionando o prefixo:

```
$table = 'news AS N, news_category AS NC';

$prefixed = "";

if (strpos($table, ', ') !== false) {
    //O explode divide a string em um array pelo primeiro parâmetro
    foreach (explode(", ", $table) as $value) {
        //Adiciona a $prefixed o valor com o prefixo
        $prefixed .= ", prefix_$value";
    }
    //Remove o primeiro prefixo
    $prefixed = trim($prefixed, ", prefix_");
    echo $prefixed;
} else { 
    echo 'FAIL'; 
}
```

Ou ainda:

```
$prefixed = implode(", prefix_", explode(", ", $table));
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar `substr([string], [começa_na_posição], [vai_ate])`, por exemplo:

```
if (substr($table, 0, 2) === ', ') {
```